# Using React-Router to link within a page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to make an anchor tag which will link to a location within the same page (like [this](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm))

However React-Router hijacks that, and and routes me to nothing, as I haven't established that link in the hierarchy.  So it sends me to the root location of that name, instead of a location on the same page.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) react router or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question, you can use hashlocation instead of history location. like this

```
ReactRouter.run(routes, hashlocation, (Handler) => {
  React.render(<Handler/>);
});
```

Comment: The router defaults to hashlocation and is already using that from root.  I don't believe you can sub-hash a hashlocation.

Comment: just create an ordinary link tag. tested and worked. also use historylocation.

  
  `<a href="#idOfComponent>Show</a>`

Comment: It seems Router.HistoryLocation only works when pairing with a server.  I'm running a simple client-side app.

Comment: i dont get what you mean. how are you suppose to run react router without a server?

Comment: Related question in reference to your answer.  Hoping you can help me clarify what different things are here.  I'm using  <Router history={browserHistory} /> so I don't get how I can relate what I"m using to your answer....what is hashLocation vs. historyLocation?  I think I'm using historyLocation which is browserHistory???

Comment: @PositiveGuy this is an old version of the library. react-router moved away from using hash, but you can still use hashrouter, so historyLocation now has 2 types - browserHistory and memoryHistory. read more on the react-router-dom docs to know whats the difference.